# SASS Complaining About Valid CSS

Tags: css, sass

New to SASS. Why am I getting the following warning?

```
$ sass --watch index.s.css:index.css --debug-info
WARNING on line 13 of index.s.css:
This selector doesn't have any properties and will not be rendered.
      error index.s.css (Line 15: Invalid CSS after "border-box": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";")
```

Lines 13–18:

```
*
{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I should note that this has nothing to do with the vendor prefixes, which I’ve tried removing. I also changed `box-sizing: border-box` to `color: pink`. Still complains.

**Edit:** I didn’t realize SASS had two syntaxes, nor that they were selected based on the filename extension. I want to use SCSS, but have to name the files `*.s.css` because I’m using the Adobe Brackets beta, which currently only has syntax highlighting for plain CSS files. I discovered the `--scss` flag to force that syntax, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Also have a look at http://compass-style.org/ it adds some nice features to SASS. Like browser prefixing. `@include box-sizing(border-box)` is one of them.

Comment: Might be worth switching back to the normal scss file extension and see if thats the cause.   Your code should work in .scss files. I   tested it in my local setup.    Also, what version of sass are you running?

Comment: Fwiw, Brackets will [add SASS syntax highlighting soon](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/pull/2609).

Comment: `expected expression … was ";"` is typical when sass is expecting the SASS syntax (which has no semicolons) and gets the SCSS syntax instead. Try `--scss` again or with the `scss` extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write it as:

```
*
 +box-sizing(border-box)
```

Try this and see if you still get the same error. If this doesn't work, try selecting some actual elements: `div, section, artcle, figure` etc.

Comment: Why? I thought SASS was a superset of CSS.

Comment: scss is, but not sass, so you'll probably want to use `sass --scss …` instead. Or (much better imo) go for [Compass](http://compass-style.org) instead.

Comment: Realized that and edited my post to reflect it. Hasn’t gotten rid of the warning though.